# Advanced File Manager app that supports a file name list

Tags: filemanager, open-source

I would be grateful if someone can help me identify an Ubuntu open source app that will allow me to move files (not copy files) from various sub-folders over to a single destination folder using a text file name list to drive the entire operation. I tried using the RSYNC command inside the terminal but had no success. Therefore, my focus now is to find an open source app that offers advanced file management capabilities straight out of the box. Thank you for your time.

SYSTEM INFO: Ubuntu 18 LTS - Bionic Beaver 64Bit

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]
And, if you want to work from a list, script it and use mv http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mv.1.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use terminal file manager [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) with which you can select files from multiple directories and move all of them to a destination directory in a single go.